# Does the order of #include directives and "using" statements matter at the beginning of a C++ header file?

Tags: c++, include, header-files, declaration, using

I am cleaning up a C++ header file and have noticed something like the following:

```
#if !defined(HEADER_H_)
#define HEADER_H_

#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#include<stdio.h>

#include "Blar/ObjA/Model.h"

namespace blar{
  class Blar;
}

#include <Blar/Blar.h>
#include <Blar/ObjB/OtherModel.h>

using namespace blar;

#include <Utilities/OtherThing.h>  
#include <qstringlist.h>
```

Is this just bad practice, or do some of the ramifications of each `#include/using/namespace` related declaration actually depend on the order? Since there is no code in between, I wouldn't think so, but I'm not familiar with too many subtleties...

Comment: Generally, it's best to put standard headers, then third-party ones, then your own, then any using declarations.

Comment: `using namespace blar;` in a header is maybe also bad practice.

Comment: `#include` inserts the contents of the specified file during compilation.  Can the `#include` order matter?  Yes.  Should it?  Usually not.  Does it in this case?  Who knows for the non-standard headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the headers are properly written it doesn't matter. If they have inter-dependencies it makes a great deal of difference.

```
// header 1
#undef FOO
#define FOO 1

// header 2
#undef FOO
#define FOO 2
```

That's a silly example, but it's fairly easy, if you're not careful, to get similar conflicts without using the preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't matter which includes you put first, so long as all of the includes are within the`#if !defined(HEADER_H_)`, but I like to put all of my standard libraries at the first,however this is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The order of `#include`'s and `using`'s doesn't matters. But it's not a good programming practice as the code becomes less readable. So write all the `#include`'s at one place and all the namespaces at one place.

Ex:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace xyz;
```